# Address and Coordinates not displaying in Mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

OK, I have tried to get this to work and I cant seem to get the addresses and coordinates from places to store in MySql database from my PHP form.  Any help will lower my cortisol levels significantly :)

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {

include('dbconn.php');

$con = mysqli_connect(db_host, db_user, db_pass, db_name);

    $value1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
    $value2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['address']);
    $value3 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['postcode']);
    $value4 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lat']);
    $value5 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lng']);

    $sqlinsert  = "INSERT INTO cafes (name, address, postcode, lat, lng) VALUES ('$value1', '$value2', '$value3', '$value4', '$value5')";

    if (!mysqli_query($con, $sqlinsert)) {
        die('error inserting new record');
    }
    $newrecord = "1 new address added to database";

}
?>


<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>DB Upload</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Insert New Address</h1>
 <form id="myForm" method="post" action="index3.php">
 <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true">
<fieldset>
<legend>New PLaces</legend>
<label>Name<input type="text" name="name"></label>
<label>Address<input type="text" name="address"></label>
<label>Postcode<input type="text" name="postcode"></label>
<label>Latitude<input type="text" name="lat"></label>
<label>Longitude<input type="text" name="lng"></label>
</fieldset>
<input type="submit" name="sub" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php
echo $newrecord
?>

</body>
</html>
```

The connection is there and here is what displays in my existing table every time:

[image]

I know you don't need to include the 'id' as auto increment, however, I have a feeling that is whats causing the problem.

Any help appreciated!!

Comment: ID has nothing to do with it, your SQL is fine. Are you running your php before, or after the HTML form is submitted? In the current format, your php runs before the form is submitted, so no value is sent to DB

Comment: What is in $value4 and $value5, what type are the columns?

Comment: What do you see if you `echo $sqlinsert;` before executing the query?

Comment: For one thing, you're mixing `MySQL_` and `MySQLi`, that's sure to put a stick in your spokes.

Comment: Change `$value1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);` to `$value1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['name']);` and do the same for the others and it will work.

Comment: Ah many thanks, Fred - It works!  And thanks for the rest of the comments!

Comment: @DarronDonaldson You're welcome. I will put it in as answer, that way we can close the question and won't remain in the "unanswered" category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Change:**

```
$value1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
```

**To:**

```
$value1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['name']);
```

and do the same for the others and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Use [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) instead of mysql_real_escape_string